# unable to load marker in react leaflet next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, next.js, react-leaflet

I am unable to load react leaflet Marker in next.js.

Here I called my map component.

```
const MapSearch = dynamic(import('../../components/Map'), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => (
    <div style={{textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: 20}}>
      Chargement…
    </div>
  )
})

const Map = () => (
    <MapSearch />
)
```

Here is my component

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';

import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

const LeafletMap = () => {
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({
    lat: 51.505,
    lng: -0.09,
    zoom: 13,
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const L = require("leaflet");

    delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

    L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
       iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
       shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png')
    });
  }, []);
  const position = [coordinates.lat, coordinates.lng];
  return (
    <Map center={position} zoom={coordinates.zoom} style={{ width: '100%', height: '600px' }}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
        url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Marker position={position}>
        <Popup>
          <span>
            Marker 1 <br /> Easily customizable.
          </span>
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </Map>
  );
};


export default LeafletMap;
```

I was getting error you need to add loader to handle png files. So from google search i have added next.config.js and added the below code

```
 module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
      loader: require.resolve("url-loader")
    });

    return config;
  }
};
```

now when i load the page map is loading but Marker is not loading. When i inspect the marker img src is taking as object module.

I also tried by removing L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions line but in that case i am getting error http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/marker-icon.1e8408af1a34bdf614570719b0d6e5ce.png%22)marker-icon.png 404 (Not Found).

I am new to Next.js.

Answer (score 3):

I may have a solution for you

I had the same issue than you and I this work for me :

I used this library : https://github.com/ghybs/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility

first run the following command :

```
npm install leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility --save
```

Then on you file where you try to implement the map (for me it is Map.js) simply add the followings imports :

```
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.webpack.css'; // Re-uses images from ~leaflet package
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility';
```

Reload your page and you should see the Marker as it should be.